# Create Table From Query Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php

I have a very complex query that pulls in information from ~10 tables, I'd like to then print those results to a table.

Here's my attempt:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE [DATA OUTPUT TABLE] AS (SELECT * FROM [Data Export]);"
```

Where [DATA OUTPUT TABLE] is intended as the new table name and [Data Export] is the name of the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost immediately found the answer:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO [DATA OUTPUT TABLE] FROM [Data Export];"
```

Comment: Works like a dream.